# org-mode text expansion macro in src block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, macroexpansion

Is it possible to use an org-mode `#+MACRO:` in an org-babel block?

I'm getting this in the `#+RESULTS:` block when I evaluate the `src` block with <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>:

```
    #+MACRO: COMPILE_FLAGS -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -pedantic
    #+begin_src shell
    echo $"{{{COMPILE_FLAGS}}}"
    #+end_src
    
    #+RESULTS:
    : {{{COMPILE_FLAGS}}}
```

But I expected this:

```
#+MACRO: COMPILE_FLAGS -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -pedantic
#+begin_src shell
echo $"{{{COMPILE_FLAGS}}}"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -pedantic
```

The [org-mode documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Macro-Replacement.html) does not hint that source blocks are treated differently, so am I doing this wrong, or should I use a different approach?

EDIT - I just realized that macro expansion is listed under "exporting" so maybe that's my problem... I am evaluating a code block, not "exporting" a document. But I'd still like a solution to replacing the macros when evaluating a code block.

Comment: That's correct: macro expansion happens on export only.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that. I'll leave the question open for a bit in case someone posts a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define header vars in various ways, e.g. globally:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args :var COMPILE_FLAGS="-std=c99 -Wall -Werror -pedantic"

#+begin_src shell
echo "${COMPILE_FLAGS}"
#+end_src
```

or in a property drawer in a specific section:

```
* foo
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args: :var COMPILE_FLAGS="-std=c99 -Wall -Werror -pedantic"
:END:

#+begin_src shell
  echo "${COMPILE_FLAGS}"
#+end_src
```

or in the source block itself:

```
* foo
#+begin_src shell :var COMPILE_FLAGS="-std=c99 -Wall -Werror -pedantic"
  echo "${COMPILE_FLAGS}"
#+end_src
```

You can also specify a language for a header-arg, so that it will only be applied to code blocks of the specified language:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args:shell :var COMPILE_FLAGS="-std=c99 -Wall -Werror -pedantic"
```

And then there are various rules for what supersedes what - see [Using Header Arguments](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Using-Header-Arguments) for details.

You cannot do it with MACRO, because, as you surmised, macros are only expanded during export.

Comment: Alternatively one can use [noweb references](https://orgmode.org/manual/Noweb-Reference-Syntax.html). Just let one Elisp block -- let's name it `blockWithString` -- evaluate to the string and refer to that block as noweb function call `<<blockWithString()>>` in another block.